# Importing a dynamically generated model class in `__init__.py`

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have a function that returns django models class and would like to import them in my `app/models/__init__.py`.

My function is a slight modification of this [dynamic model exemple (Django Wiki)](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels#Ageneral-purposeapproach). It clones a model and returns a `<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>`, a slightly modified "shadow model".

Just like one would do (in `app/models/__init__.py`) `from a import test1`, I would like to do something like:

```
from c import modeltocopy
from b import dynamic_model('ShadowModel', app_label='fake',fields=modeltocopy._meta.fields)`
```

I want to do this in order to create tables in an alternative db from my dynamic models.

Is such a thing possible?

My currently working solution is a management command that is a modification of `django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py` that creates tables from a tuple of tuples defined in `settings.py` (`SHADOW_MODELS = (('app.module1.module_a', 'ClassName1'),)`).
 It does work but I am being asked to import my dynamic models in `/app/models/__init__.py` rather than having to run a separate command just for my dynamic models.

Comment: What do you expect the `from b import dynamic_model('ShadowModel', app_label='fake',fields=modeltocopy._meta.fields)` to do? Execute `dynamic_model('ShadowModel', app_label='fake',fields=modeltocopy._meta.fields)` then import the resulting name from `b`? Or to import `dynamic_model` from `b` then execute that?

Comment: execute `b.dynamic_model('ShadowModel', app_label='fake',fields=modeltocopy._meta.fields)` and then import its resulting class so `syncdb` can see it and create the table.

Comment: But the `dynamic_model()` call *already* returns a class, so just import `dynamic_model` from `b` then execute it in the local module, store the result in a new name: `ShadowModel = dynamic_model('ShadowModel', app_label='fake',fields=modeltocopy._meta.fields)`. Should work just fine, why doesn't that for you?

Comment: I was thinking of something much much more complicated. I did try this but made the mistake of setting `app_label='fake'` when I was running `python manage.py sqlall appname`. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import the result of a function call. Instead you could first import the function, then call it to create the model class in the module's namespace:

```
from c import modeltocopy
from b import dynamic_model as dyn_model_factory

ShadowModel = dyn_model_factory('ShadowModel', app_label='fake', fields=modeltocopy._meta.fields)
```

The resulting `dynamic_model` is then read to be imported from other module.